# Can't make fit website background (CSS)

Tags: html, css, web

How can I fit website background to the browser's height?
Here is my CSS of the background code.

```
#header {
  position: relative;
  background: url(girl.jpg) no-repeat fixed center bottom / cover transparent;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I don't want to set height:100% for the image because I don't want the long scroll down. I want neat fit background to my browser's width. Any help?

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1k18.jpg <- Here is the link to website screenshot.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle ? Thanks

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want the image of the woman to fill the screen?

Comment: Yes I want to fill the screen with woman's picture. My problem here is that I can't adjust enough picture height for a div class. Sorry for my bad English as I'm not the native speaker.

Comment: you mean you want the girl image to cover the background so the suit image bellow wont show?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
body
{
background: url(girl.jpg) no-repeat fixed center bottom / cover transparent;
}
```

add the above css code in your css file...